# SQL Server AE issue in value encryption

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc, always-encrypted

I have applied AE on a SQL Server database at column with datatype of `numeric(18,0)`. When I encrypt the data using SSMS the encryption of `154` is

```
0x01FA3FADE537BB5405E193F859FEDFBBC15C8177AB22F11B139AAB05158F685A29AED638E828BA43457C58668DC05D3DEC8612C28E7221F31BE8E4B291A1408972F186E456038E1041F376370147BCBB54
```

and I push `154` using JDBC Driver the encryption is

```
0x01D33F20C4A164160862CDD161305016053C166D4474FD21DA216C353049A8BEFC3EFE177E8FE7CD74E3BC7343D2EC51F7A8DECBD5C31E2F969A0A75D20EFCD7BC4AE0B59708971CF8EAC8C0A450ADA450
```

I am using a deterministic algorithm.

Because of this I am not able to apply where clause using JDBC. It return only those row which were pushed using JDBC after encryption.

Is there something I can fix to match both the encrypted values?

Comment: What does your Java code look like? Are you using the `setBigDecimal` overloads that include the `precision` and `scale` parameters?

Comment: Yes. I am using setBigDecmial(paramIndex, value, 18, 6);

Comment: Do you think that could be your problem? The column data type is `numeric(18,0)` so to match it have you tried using `setBigDecmial(paramIndex, value, 18, 0);`?

Comment: I found the problem. SSMS is using Dotnet lib to encrypt the data and java using java based. So if we push the data in encrypted Numeric columns encryption will be different for same plain text. For example : 
Plain Text       ||     Java based Encryption    ||   Dot Net Based Encryption 
ABC               |||    0xabasdfjkerwkjljasdkfjl  |||  0xerwersdfasdfasdfasdfs